# Python - Import txt in a sequential pattern

Tags: python, import, text-files

In the directory I have say, 30 txt files each containing two columns of numbers with roughly 6000 numbers in each column. What i want to do is to import the first 3 txt files, process the data which gives me the desired output, then i want to move onto the next 3 txt files.

The directory looks like:

file0a

file0b

file0c

file1a

file1b

file1c ... and so on.

I don't want to import *all* of the txt files simultaneously, I want to import the first 3, process the data, then the next 3 and so forth. I was thinking of making a dictionary - though i have a feeling this might involve writing each file name in the dictionary, which would take far too long.

EDIT:

For those that are interested, I think i have come up with a work around. Any feedback would greatly be appreciated, since i'm not sure if this is the quickest way to do things or the most pythonic.

```
import glob

def chunks(l,n):
  for i in xrange(0,len(l),n):
    yield l[i:i+n]


   Data = []

   txt_files = glob.iglob("./*.txt")

   for data in txt_files:
     d = np.loadtxt(data, dtype = np.float64)
     Data.append(d)

   Data_raw_all  = list(chunks(Data,3))
```

Here the list 'Data' is all of the text files from the directory, and 'Data_raw_all' uses the function 'chunks' to group the elements in 'Data' into sets of 3. This way you can selecting one element in Data_raw_all selects the corresponding 3 text files in the directory.

Comment: You won't be able to open the files without the file names. Are they actually named file1a etc. or are those placeholders?

Comment: The file names are called UVF2CNa1ai, UVF2CNa1aj and UVF2CNa1ak. For berevity, however, i called them file1a and so on. Assuming they are called file1a etc - could this be done?

Comment: So are the filenames grouped by the same first 8 characters, and then seperated in groups by ending with i, j and k?

Comment: The first 7 characters remain unchanged, the last characters change periodically like i,j,k. The 9th character changes from a to b to c after ever i,j,k - then the number 1 increases to 2 and the set is repeated. So the file (ignoring the unchanging first 7 characters) looks like:

1ai
1aj
1ak

1bi
1bj
1bk

1ci
1cj
1ck

2ai
2aj
2ak and so on.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I have nothing original to include here and I definitely do not want to claim credit for it at all because it all comes from the *Python Cookbook 3rd Ed* and from this [wonderful presentation on generators](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators-uk/GeneratorsUK.pdf) by David Beazley (one of the co-authors of the aforementioned *Cookbook*). However, I think you might really benefit from the examples given in the slideshow on generators.

What Beazley does is chain a bunch of generators together in order to do the following:

1. yields filenames matching a given filename pattern.
2. yields open file objects from a sequence of filenames.
3. concatenates a sequence of generators into a single sequence
4. greps a series of lines for those that match a regex pattern

All of these code examples are located [here](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators-uk/). The beauty of this method is that the chained generators simply chew up the `next` pieces of information: they don't load *all* files into memory in order to process *all* the data. It's really a nice solution.

Anyway, if you read through the slideshow, I believe it will give you a blueprint for exactly what you want to do: you just have to change it for the information you are seeking.

In short, check out the slideshow linked above and follow along and it should provide a blueprint for solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm presuming you want to hardcode as few of the file names as possible. Therefore most of this code is for generating the filenames. The files are then opened with a `with` statement.

Example code:

```
from itertools import cycle, count

root = "UVF2CNa"

for n in count(1):
    for char in cycle("abc"):
        first_part = "{}{}{}".format(root, n, char)
        try:
            with open(first_part + "i") as i,\
                 open(first_part + "j") as j,\
                 open(first_part + "k") as k:
                # do stuff with files i, j and k here
                pass
        except FileNotFoundError:
            # deal with this however
            pass
```